# Выбор элементов combobox на сайте программно

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть сайт, в нем 2 комбобокса, нужно сделать фокус на 1ом комбобоксе и выбрать в нем элемент, затем поставить фокус на 2ой комбобокс и выбрать в нем элемент.
Вот код

```
HtmlWindow frames = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
        frames = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0];
        var elements1 = frames.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
        elements1[0].Focus();
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
        elements1[1].Focus();
```

Как видно, элементы внутри комбобокса я выбираю имитацией нажатия клавиши вниз на клавиатуре. В итоге получается, что выбор происходит во втором комбобоксе, такое ощущение, что не успевает поставить фокус, как нажимается клавиша вниз.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно поправить? Или может есть более разумный способ выбора элементов комбобокса, нежелеи имитация нажатия клавиши клавиатуры. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуюсь вот такой конструкцией, работает стабильно, можно конечно добавить проверок если есть необходимость:

```
#region Выбор элемента в выпадающем списке
/// <summary>
/// Выбор элемента в выпадающем списке
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aValue">Текст пункта который необходимо выбрать в выпадающем списке</param>
/// <returns>В случае невозможности выбора False</returns>
public bool SelectItemFromListbox(string aValue)
{
    HtmlElementCollection a_tag = FCurrentWebBrowser.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
    foreach (HtmlElement he in a_tag)
    {
        if (he.GetAttribute("name").Equals("ИМЯ СПИСКА"))
        {
            he.SetAttribute("value", aValue);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
#endregion


#region Ожидание полной загрузки веб страницы Webbrowser
/// <summary>
/// Ожидание полной загрузки веб страницы Webbrowse
/// </summary>
/// <param name="aCurWebBrowser">Ссылка на WebBrowser завершение загрузки веб страницы в котором следует дождаться</param>
public static void FullLoadWebPage(WebBrowser aCurWebBrowser)
{
    while (aCurWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: Может быть Вы подскажите, почему если я одной кнопкой нажимаю 2 значения комбобокса и еще одну кнопку, то все отрабатывает как надо, но если я помещаю этот код в цикл, программа зависает. Хотя выход из цикла есть логический.

Comment: поставь BreakPoint в цикле и посмотри, происходит выход или нет, отладка штука полезная

Comment: Отладкой я уже пробежался несколько раз... такое ощущения, что из-за того, что я кнопку не сам нажимаю, а в цикле, сайт не успевает отвечать на запросы, и может поэтому он никак не может выйти из цикла

Comment: кстати да, Вы же получается нажимаете на кнопку и происходит отправка информации на сайт, а браузер не успевает полностью загрузить все, а Вы идете по дереву элементов. значит необходимо дожидаться полной загрузки страницы, либо делать sleep))

Comment: Ну вот слип попробовал как раз - не помогает... если делать обработчик события, который дожидается конца загрузки, то что в нем должно быть? В цикле то понятно, я один раз пробежался и зарегистрировал обработчик события, а дальше что...

Comment: В IE беда, как раз с событием DocumentCompleted оно вызывается для каждого фрейма(. а Sleep куда прописывал?

Comment: Слип в конце цикла ставлю на пол секунды, но он работает странно как-то, сначало спит, а потом кнопку жмет. но это при условии того, что я поставил, что бы по циклу 2 прохода делало, если ставлю 3 уже зависает

Comment: попробуй вызвать в конце цикла FullLoadWebPage(webBrowser1), не факт что поможет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39572/discussion-between---and-nmd).